# getting error while adding a jar library. What could possibly go wrong?

Tags: android, import, jar

I have added a jar file as the library,and i know their existence by importing its class, but somehow it cannot compile properly.

I've attached the screenshot.

[image: Image of IDE]

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You have two main issues here

1. It looks as if you did not update your gradle file and instead simply just added the javax.jar dependency to your project ( this is a guess based on your post )
2. More importantly, **you cannot import JEE into an Android project**

Gradle is used for build automation and dependency management.  You import dependencies into your Android application by updating your Gradle file to include the dependency you wish to include ( I recommend looking up the dependency on [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/) since it will include your Gradle modification ).

> I cannot say what to use instead of javax ( JEE ) without knowing your specific use case.

Comment: I did update the build.gradle file: implementation files('libs/javax.jar'); and I want to achieve while running program, users input a string of code, and dynamically create a class having this code as a function and execute it

Comment: You can't use javax.jar in an Android project. That is a fact